# Calculating count over partition

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I want to make a new column which specifies count of mileage for each car. The output should look like this:

[image]

Basically, the new column is counting the occurrences for the mileage for EACH car type.

Here's what I'm using in my SQlite query:

```html
SELECT
*,
COUNT(Mileage) OVER (PARTITION BY Mileage ORDER BY Car) Count_mileage
FROM car_table
GROUP BY Car, Mileage
```

However, it does not give the accurate answer, as it takes count of mileage without partitioning into cars.

Can anybody help.

Comment: I don't understand the expected output.  Can you better explain the logic there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partition should be over `Car` also and there is no need for the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Car, Mileage) Count_mileage
FROM car_table
```

Also the `GROUP BY` clause is not needed.